# How would ballistics, rocketry and orbital mechanics work on a ring world?

Tags: physics, hard-science, rockets

I'm new here so sorry if my formatting sucks but I was wondering how rocketry and orbital mechanics would work on a ring world?

I was thinking my ring world would be 1 AU in radius, 80,150km in length. I haven't decided on the thickness or the mass yet.

The ring would generate gravity by spinning. According to [Issac Arthur's Ringworld](https://youtu.be/yk-Ivm9MhYs) it would have to spin at 1200km per second and rotate once every 9 days.

There will be a sun identical to our own in the middle, and an inner ring somewhere in between the main ring and the sun. The inner ring will control the lighting, day night cycles, the climate, pretty much anything to do with the sky.

What I want to know is how would a civilization native to the ring world utilize rocketry. Would it be useful to travel within the ring world? How would the gravity of the sun affect the trajectory of rockets making trips between two different points on the ring world?

Would it be possible to launch stuff into orbit? If so, what would that orbit look like? Could you make an orbit for a sattalite to map out the entire ring? Could you make something orbit around the ring like a moon?

Also what happens if someone builds a rocket and goes 1200km per second in the opposite direction of the ring world's spin? Would the rocket fall to the sun?

Sorry if this is not the format people usually ask questions in, I'm new here

Comment: Yes, you can put things into orbit. No it won't be like sattelites going around earth. As your ring-world encircles the sun, stable orbits "around" the ring-world will appear to move slowly "above" or "below" the ring and will move around the ring.

Comment: Seems like your formatting is less troublesome than the hour of your post but you should get some feedback when people wake up in a few hours.  In the meantime, you might want to focus your post around a single question.  As it currently stands, it might get closed for asking too many questions for a single post.  We tend towards one question per post here.
My knowledge of gravitation & orbital dynamics aren't sufficient for your "hard-science" tag but I can predict what the big brains will say.  The only source of mass sufficient to provide an orbit-able gravity well is the star at the hub.

Comment: I saw that another question that has already been answered was linked at the top for me. I had already seen that answer, but it does fail to account for the gravity of the sun in that situation, how would that change things?

Comment: If you throw a ball do you think the sun's gravity is having any appreciable effect on its trajectory? We're 1 AU away, as is your ring's surface. You've also asked several questions, so even if reopened to factor in another gravity well, it would be closed for that reason.